# Use structured template in numbered list

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there any way to include a structured template (`#+Begin/end_SRC`) in the middle of a numbered list without ruining the numbering?

Here is a MWE:

```
1) First question

#+begin_quote
    Quote needed for first question
#+end_quote

1) Second question
```

When I try to export it or update the numbering, the second question is assigned number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done: do not leave more than one empty line and indent the block properly:

```
* Questions

1) First question

   #+begin_quote
     Quote needed for first question
   #+end_quote

1) Second question
```

You can insert the block properly indented by pressing `TAB` which should indent to the right place (under the F in "First question") and then `C-c C-, q` (`q` for `quote`, but any of the choices will do) to insert the template. After you insert the template, you can add the contents - pressing `TAB` at the end should indent the contents properly.

Or you can insert the contents properly indented (`TAB` should work - assuming that the option `org-cycle-emulate-tag` is set to `t`, the default - to get the ball rolling: after entering the first line at the right indentation, the rest should indent properly). Then mark the contents as a region and *then* do `C-c C-, q` to wrap the region inside the template.

Thanks to @Tobias for the kick to make me get it right (I think and hope it's right, but if there are problems, let me know).

Comment: 1.) Note that single newlines do not break the item sequence but "wrong" indentation does. 2.) I think you missed the question a bit. The OP wants to know how one can insert a correctly indented block **using structure templates**. But, structure templates are not discussed at all in your answer.

Comment: @Tobias, I could have sworn that empty lines broke the sequence, so I didn't even test: now that I have, you are right (as usual). Re. 2) I expanded it quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `org-tempo` you should first indent the line before inserting the template shortcut `<q` for the quote-block.

That means if you have the input

```
1. First question

|
```

where the bar `|` stands for the cursor position, type <kbd>TAB</kbd> to arrive at the indented position as shown in the following code:

```
1. First question

   |
```

then input the structure template `<q`:

```
1. First question

   <q|
```

Now, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> for template expansion and you get:

```
1. first

   #+BEGIN_QUOTE
   |
   #+END_QUOTE
```

When you place the cursor behind `#+END_QUOTE` and press <kbd>M-<RET></kbd> you get the next item with number 2:

```
1. first

   #+BEGIN_QUOTE

   #+END_QUOTE

2. |
```

That already indicates that the numbering is fine.

Note that I just corrected [org-structtempl.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/org-structtempl/) to obtain a similar behavior with that package.

(`org-structtempl.el` gives the old structure template behavior back in Org > 9.2 and adds some more features, e.g. expansion of LaTeX environments through key `<m`).